# Conversion from Color image to 8-bit gray scale

Tags: r, jpeg, grayscale, 8-bit

I use R for image processing (packages EBImage)

I have an input 'jpeg' image, which upon reading in 'R' and trying `print(Input_Image)` gives me the following output Image

```
  colorMode    : Color 
  storage.mode : double 
  dim          : 3888 2592 3 
  frames.total : 3 
  frames.render: 1
```

Now, I would like to convert this **Color** type input image to **8-bit** **Grayscale** image type.

I am exhausted with manual and internet search but couldn't find a a solution.  As I expect end result to be 8-bit, maximum value of the output grayscale image would be 255.

Using the functions readily available in R EBImage I am only able to get a Grayscale image of type double meaning values are in the range 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The image(s) can be converted into gray scale by modifying the attribute of `colorMode`. Using the file linked in the comments one could try :

```
library("EBImage")
img <- readImage("16_left.jpg")
```

With this the file has been read and stored in `img` (assuming that the JPEG file is in the working directory).

```
> img
Image 
colorMode    : Color 
storage.mode : double 
dim          : 1279 853 3 
frames.total : 3 
frames.render: 1 
...
```

Now the image can be converted into gray scale using

```
img@colormode <- Grayscale
```

or

```
colorMode(img) = Grayscale
```

The converted image can then be stored as a PNG file:

```
writeImage(img,file="16_left_bw.png")
```

In this example three images are stored in the working directory, `16_left_bw-0.png`, `16_left_bw-1.png`, and `16_left_bw-2.png`

Here is the first of these images:

[image]

According to an analysis with a standard image viewer (here I used ubuntu's ImageMagick), the image is stored in 8-bit format. The data is still stored in double format and ranges from 0 to 1

```
> range(img@.Data)
[1] 0 1
```

but only 256 levels are used:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice working example! I followed the same commands for converting my Input color Image of type double to 8-bit gray scale. Input image posted in URL: http://postimg.org/image/wb7txoill/ But couldn't achieve the 8-bit gray scale. Output checked and validated using print command of R. I am surely missing some thing purely technical.

Comment: @user2701513 I updated the post using your file. I hope this helps. It seems that, although the levels of the gray scale image are not explicitly stored in a range from 0 to 255, they are binned such that the image is treated as an 8-bit image which uses levels between 0 and 255.

Comment: Guess, the important message in here is ** the levels of the gray scale image are not explicitly stored in a range from 0 to 255 ** Guess I have to find a way to translate to explicit 0-255 8-bit range.